# DatePicker dialog: header background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker

I'm creating a DatePicker dialog programaticlly and set a style to it to set the header color
this is the style

```
 <style name="MyDatePickerWidgetStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">#46C9EB</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#46C9EB</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#46C9EB</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#46C9EB</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#46C9EB</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
  </style>
```

most of the phone it look great but on "Huawei P smart z" it look like this [image]

The background is cut

```
DatePickerDialog(
            mContext,R.style.MyDatePickerWidgetStyle,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val newDate = Calendar.getInstance()
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
                mDiaryPresenter.setDailyDiaryList(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
            },
            year,
            month,
            day
```

Comment: And how should it look like? How do you create it (Material library?)?

Comment: i updated the post the header backgroud width should match the parent layout